# Mongo aggregation framework: what is the lock level of the last stage $out operation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Using Mongo's aggregation pipeline it is possible to write query result to a collection (existent or new) using `$out` stage, like that

```js
db.my_collection.aggregate([ { $match: { my_field: 'my_value' } }, { $out: 'my_new_collection' } ])
```

The question is what kind of lock does Mongo use while writing to `my_new_collection`? Is it a 'regular' write lock, or a *global* lock, like Map Reduce?

[Map Reduce lock reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce-concurrency/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is always a certain level of locking that depending on your MongoDB version is either likely to be collection or in older the database level, or even possibly document level with the WiredTiger storage engine. The [`$out`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) does however yield on writes, so indvidual documents are output from the pipeline and not all in one go, so each update is atomic per document.

Even the mapReduce command [has this option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#output-to-a-collection-with-an-action), where you can set "nonAtomic" as a condition where the output collection of a mapReduce will exhibit the same behavior.

The one thing to be aware of with `$out` will remove all documents ( not replace any existing indexes ) from a collection as that stage executes when using the "replace" mode. So attempting to read or write from a collection directed with "replace" set is very likely to to fail (or produce unexpected results) whilst the aggregation operation is in progress.

The other limitations relating to sharded collections and capped collections are noted in the documentation.

Comment: thanks, that answers my question. On a side note: is there any place in the official documentation where it's stated _explicitly_ that `$out` works on a per - document level? Or is it so, that it's assumed, because it's the way Mongo normally operates, unless stated otherwise.

Comment: @szymek You are misquoting me there. I did not say "document locking level" outside of using the WiredTiger storage engine. "Atomic" document updates and "locking" are two different things concurrency wise. What I said is it "yields", threfore allowing other operations to happen while the document stream is being written. Sadly, no documentation. Just run tests.

Comment: sure you're right, took some mental shortcuts there and got all mixed up. Thanks for `yield` explanation

Comment: You mentioned that "$out will remove all documents ... when using the 'replace' mode".  Is there a way to use $out in anything other than replace mode?