# Update to average value in Mongo document with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb

I want to update field in exists mongodb document. But set value should be average value of old value and new value.

I can get old value from mongodb document and calculate average value, and set into field, but it's not thread safety and old value in mongodb document might change while I calculate average.

Example, document:

> {
>       '_id': ObjectId("55d49338b9796c337c894df3"),
>       value: 10 }

Python code:

```
# new_value = 15, therefore average_value = 12.5
db.mycollection.update_one(
    {'_id': '55d49338b9796c337c894df3'},
    {...} <- What there?
)
```

Before:

> {
>       '_id': ObjectId("55d49338b9796c337c894df3"),
>       value: 12.5 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework to do update. The pipeline steps you need for this are **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** and **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)**. The **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** operator allows you to replace an existing fields within the collection with results from
an expression, which would involve the arithmetic operator **[`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg)** to compute the average.

The **[`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg)** operator, if used in the [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#use-in-project-stage) (or **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)**) stage, can accept a list of expressions and with that list you can push values from the existing field and the new value for computing the average
of these two.

The **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** operator as the final stage will update the existing collection as it writes the resulting documents of the aggregation pipeline to a collection.

The following example describes the above update operation disguised as an aggregate operation:

```
new_value = 15
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
        "value": { "$avg":  ["$value", new_value] }
    } },
    { "$out": "mycollection" }
])
```

or with MongoDB 3.2 using **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** as

```
new_value = 15
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "value": { "$avg":  ["$value", new_value] }
    } },
    { "$out": "mycollection" }
])
```

Comment: `aggregate()` operations use [read locks](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#which-operations-lock-the-database) and your question can be best explained by Blakes Seven [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31837306).

Comment: @chridam Unfortunately this approach will not work -- as at MongoDB 3.4, you cannot use the aggregation framework to perform an update to an existing collection. The `$out` operator will either [create a new collection in the current database](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#create-new-collection) (if one does not exist already) or [**replace** the target collection if it already exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#replace-existing-collection).

Comment: Relevant feature request to watch/upvote: [SERVER-12280: allow $out to append to/merge with existing collection instead of replacing it](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12280).

Comment: Thanks @Stennie for the links

Comment: Oh, great! Thank you!